# How to use a different properties filename in Koin?

Tags: kotlin, koin

The default properties file for Koin is `koin.properties`.

How to use a different properties file name instead?

A snippet from the [documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/properties):

```
startKoin {
    // Load properties from the default location
    // (i.e. `/src/main/resources/koin.properties`)
    fileProperties()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(sharing my findings)*

`fileProperties()` accepts an optional `fileName` argument which defaults to `'/koin.properties'`.

To use a different filename, it must be passed to `fileProperties` **with a leading slash**.

For example, to use `application.properties`, call:

```
fileProperties("/application.properties")
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work with an absolute path. Is it by design that all property locations must be on the classpath to work?